# Background zoom

Tags: css, анимация, css-animation

Здравствуйте. Я новичок, и хотелось понять, как  работает этот зум. Вот на этом сайте я увидел это: http://hq-ds.com/
Подскажите, возможно ли сделать это на css animation, или без js не обойтись? Буду благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что в его содержимом не приведено описание желаемого эффекта. Ссылки на сторонние ресурсы могут служить лишь поясняющим дополнением.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> возможно ли сделать это на css animation, или без js не обойтись?

Возможно, например, с использованием `keyframes`.

```css
#mf {
  background: url(http://jhealth.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/megan-fox-sexy-photo.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width:375px;
  height:375px;
  z-index:5;
  position:absolute;

 
  -webkit-animation: mfox 5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: mfox 5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mfox {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}

@keyframes mfox {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mf"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Подобное увеличение делается посредством длительной анимации свойства `scale`
https://jsfiddle.net/pfed7nk8/

Comment: Ну а как сделать чтоб не :hover, а при запуске страницы?